# C++ - Splitting int into two smaller data types

Tags: c++, split, bit-manipulation

I am trying to split an int variable into two parts of arbitrary length (ie: splitting 32 bits into 31 and 1 bits, 30 and 2 bits, 16 and 16 bits, 1 and 31 bits etc).

I have tried to implement it using the bitwise shift operators, however cant seem to get it work correctly.

```
int botLength = 4;
int start = ~0;
int top = start << botLength;
int bottom = start - top;

std::cout << "Top:    " << std::bitset<32>(top) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Bottom: " << std::bitset<32>(bottom) << std::endl;
```

This outputs

```
Top:    11111111111111111111111111110000
Bottom: 00000000000000000000000000001111
```

Where as I want:

```
Top:    00001111111111111111111111111111
Bottom: 00000000000000000000000000001111
```

I thought I could fix this by changing the code to the following:

```
int botLength = 4;
int start = ~0;
int top = start << botLength;
int bottom = start - top;
top = top >> botLength; //added this

std::cout << "Top:    " << std::bitset<32>(top) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Bottom: " << std::bitset<32>(bottom) << std::endl;
```

However this seems to add 1s as the padding, as it outputs this:

```
Top:    11111111111111111111111111111111
Bottom: 00000000000000000000000000001111
```

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

Comment: I think using unsigned int would do the trick, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: Just for fun, `std::cout << start << std::endl`. I think you may be surprised by the result.

Comment: prints -1, but I'm still confused as to why using unsigned instead fixes it. Doesn't unsigned just tell the compiler how to interpret the data? The actual binary should still be affected in the same way with << and >> (at least that's what I thought, but it evidently doesn't ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use unsigned values such as [`uint32_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) to fix your problem. Make variable `top` unsigned.

---

Variable `top` is signed in your code

```
int botLength = 4;
int start = ~0;
int top = start << botLength;
```

Above code puts a negative value in `top`, then the sign bit at the leftmost place (the most significant bit) is `1`.

```
int bottom = start - top;
top = top >> botLength;
```

After each shift to right to keep the sign, sign bit will set to `1` again. So, you have all bits `1`.

---

In summery, compiler tries to keep the sign of a signed integer value after each shifting operation. So, this mechanism affects your algorithm and you'll not get correct result.

Comment: It does :) But now I'm curious, why?

Comment: Because if you use signed ints and the most significant bit is 1, then if you shift the value to the right you will get 1s instead of 0s in the most significant bits.

Answer (score 2):

Because in C and C++ `int` is treated as a signed number, the right shift operator copies the most significant bit, which indicates the sign. Signed numbers are encoded in [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

You should switch to `unsigned` to get the highest bit cleared when shifting right, or you can also use a cast on the fly, for example:

```
unsigned bits = 1;
int s = -1;
s = s >> bits;

int u = -1;
u = unsigned(u) >> bits;
```

after this, s will be -1 (0xFFFFFFFF), whereas u will be 2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFF)

Answer (score 0):

The most significant bit of a signed value indicates whether the value is negative or positive.  As M M. indicates, if you right shift a negative number, the operation extends the sign bit into the high order bits.

Division by 2 is equivalent to right shifting one bit.  If you divide -4 by 2, you would expect to get -2, not 6 which is what I think you would get if you didn't extend the sign.